# Is it possible to execute tests from a dependency jar in SBT?

Tags: sbt, scalatest

We have consumer driven contract tests from someone else packaged as a jar containing test specs. Now we want to execute them in our build in a submodule. But by default sbt sets the test classpath for scalatest to contain only the compilation result of src/test/scala. How can we change that to scan a test dependency jar for Suites?

Comment: Did you try adding it the jar as dependency in your project? Do you call the test code from within src/test/scala?

Comment: Yes we added it. src/test/scala is empty. What we need is to change the runpath/discovery path for tests to be found. I know how to do this with the scalatest runner, but sbt has it's own discovery and does not use the testframeworks discovery.

Comment: Are you trying to access test code from within the Run/Compile configuration? I think I need to see some basic skeleton of your .sbt build file to be able to help more.

Comment: As I've written, the tests are already pre packaged as a jar, I only want to execute them again in sbt. But the discovery per default only takes src/test/scala into account, and NOT any suites contained in test dependency jars. That's the idea behind consumer driven contract tests. The consumer of a service writes and runs the tests and packages them, so that the producer can also execute them if they change s.th. In our secenario "packaging" means: Supplying a jar with the suites in it, and those we want to run again.